# Как правильно передвигать ImageView?

Tags: android, java

Необходимо передвигать `ImageView` в `AbsoluteLayout`. Собственно, я пытаюсь как-то реализовать 
передвижение частей пазла, как это сделано, например, [тут](https://market.android.com/details?id=zok.android.shapes&feature=search_result). Поможет любая информация. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно будет не передвигать `ImageView` в `AbsoluteLayout`, а рисовать на Canvas то, что планировалось размещать в `ImageView`. Если все же перемещать вид, то делается это примерно так:

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams p = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());
p.x = getX();
p.y = getY();
v.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Вы можете обратиться к примеру из SDK [LunaLander](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html), чтобы понять лучше, как надо решать эту задачу.

Comment: спасибо) попробую